# Why does the Minecraft launcher sometimes still show the 1.17 layout?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

Now with version 1.18(.1) the Minecraft launcher layout looks different again, but sometimes when it needs longer to load the 1.17 layout still appears before being overlaid by the new 1.18 one. Why is the 1.17 layout even still loading?